# Putting a menu inside a Navmenu fragment java android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm developing a Java android app for my current school project. The app contains of a navigation menu with 3 sections.

One section contains a on swipe card view, second displays my jobs and the third one is account settings.

The second fragment my jobs is ment to be as follows:[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piclt.png)

The problem is how to set the top menu inside that certain fragment. My jobs should show one fragment containing "Jobs" that I am a part off, and the other menu option Jobs that I offer should show my listed jobs inside a recycler view and it should contain a button that opens the form to create a new job.

So far I filled up the fragment my jobs with the needed recycler view but I struggle with the menu itself.

[problematic menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEmvB.png)

Code for frag1:
public class MojiPosloviFragment extends Fragment {

```
RecyclerView recyclerPoslovi;
List<Posao> posloviD;
String nazivPoslodavca;
Intent intent;
public MojPosaoAdapter mojiPosloviAdapter;
private MojPosaoAdapter.MojPosaoClickListener listener;
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_moji_poslovi, container, false);
```

Note: That mentioned fragment is a part of navmenu!